# No me encuentra bookmark

Tags: json, mongodb

Inserto esto en mongodb, creo que es el formato correcto, al menos no me devuelve error, pero a la hora de buscarlo no lo encuentra

```
{"user": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "alex",
          "surname":"wallx",
          "email":"alex@wallx.com",
          "pass":"ads",
          "rol": "admin",
          "img": "img.jpg"
           }
    };
```

y este es el find que uso

```
db.inventory.find( { name: "alex" } )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es mas que un objeto dentro de otro, entonces deberás indicar la clave principal y la secundaria para lograr acceder a dicho valor.

```
db.collection.find({ "claveprincipal.subclaveprincipal": valor })
```

Entonces para encontrar el valor que deseas, tu query debe quedar así

```
db.inventory.find({ "user.name": "alex" })
```

Aquí tienes la referencia de la [documentación oficial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/)